# MySQL after insert triggrt

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have to change gender to 'W' of employee table after an insert operation when gender is 'M' or 'L' or 'T'.

Delimiter is $$

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_employee_insert  
AFTER INSERT ON employee  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
UPDATE employee SET gender='W' where gender in('M', 'L', 'T');  
END$$

insert into employee values(111, 'zzz', 200000, 's')$$
```

O/P

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'employee' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

Even when I am not taking M/L/T, still it's not allowing to update

should I use before insert? Tried that also
Tried with

```
where new.gender in('M', 'L', 'T');
```

O/P

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'gender' in 'NEW'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values of the current row you insert refering to `NEW`

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_employee_insert  
BEFORE INSERT ON employee  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    IF gender in('M', 'L', 'T') THEN
       SET NEW.gender = 'W';
    END IF;
END$$
```

But if you put a update statement in your trigger you get an endless loop which the DB engine prevents with an error message.